Need advice regarding usage of MassTransit/RabbitMq RPC in production
Consider the data flow from client to server and back:

Client sends an HTTP request Server1.
To process the request, Server1 calls Server 2 using MassTransit/RabbitMq RPC.
Server2 in its turn calls Server3 using MassTransit/RabbitMq RPC.
Server3 processes request and returns result to Server2.
Server2 returns reply to Server1
Server 1 sends reply to client

I did this setup in my small lab and it works perfectly fine. However, I have no idea how reliable and fast it will be in production.
Is this scheme valid in quite a big system with hundreds of parallel client requests that should be processes as fast as possible? How reliable and performant is RabbitMq RPC?
